# What is the opposite of "paying by installments"?

Tags: finance

What is the opposite of "paying by installments"? I'm looking for the proper financial term for paying in full in a single payment.

Comment: Hi @Scruffy, and welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question to clarify what *opposite* refers to here. If you meant something else by *opposite*, please feel free to roll back or [edit] further.

Comment: What's wrong with "paying in full"?

Comment: I came up with one-time payment and upfront payment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The opposite of *paying by instalments* is usually to ***pay in a lump sum***.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lump_sum) says:

> A lump sum is a single payment of money, as opposed to a series of payments made over time (such as an annuity).

Answer (score 3):

You may use the expression:

> - to pay ***in one installment***.

Or:

> - Lump sum payment. n.
>
>   - A single sum of money that serves as complete payment.
>   - A lump-sum payment is usually taken in lieu of recurring payments distributed over a period of time.

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lump-sum-payment.asp)

Answer (score 2):

If you decide that you don't want to pay by installments, you can "pay in full."